# Can GitLab pages show index.html in a different directory?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

GitLab (specifically Gitlab.com), not Github.

I'm using Gulp and producing a `release` folder with my processed files.

```
release/
  index.html
src/
```

When making this work for GitLab pages, can I have it use `release/index.html`? I still need the `src/` folder in the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

The HTML files need to be in a folder called `public` at the root of your repository.

If you rename the `release` folder to `public` then you have to create a job named `pages` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. You can even do the renaming within that job.

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mv release public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

Comment: Follow up question, then: if I rename `release` to public, will Pages automatically pick it up, or will I need to edit the gitlab-ci.yml file somehow?